# How to overlay graphics from raw Raspberry Pi camera data?

Tags: c, camera, raspberry-pi, video-capture, video-processing

I'm writing an application using MMAL. Much of how the hardware (camera module) was set up was derived from [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam/RaspiVid.c). The purpose of the application is to overlay a texture onto the video stream and onto a file using the H.264 video file format.

It would be ideal if I would be able to receive a callback of sorts with a buffer of raw RGBA data, manipulate it (overlay the raw texture), and send it off to the encoder.

Conceptually, I have a camera and encoder component. The camera component has a video output port, while the encoder component has both an input and output port. The video output port is connected to the encoder input port. In the encoder output port, a callback is registered and at each callback, the buffer data is appended to a file stream.

I attempted to register a callback on the video port, but a simple `printf()` inside the video output port yields no output.

Is this possible? If so, what exactly am I missing?

Edit: I have added the splitter component and have made the following connections: **VideoOutputPort -> Splitter -> H.264Encoder** with no luck.

Edit: I'm looking into using **libavcodec**